# How to run multiple modal forms in sequence in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, modal-dialog

I have a method RunForm() that runs a modal dialog performing some task:

```
    static void RunForm() {
        SomeForm    form = new SomeForm();
        Application.Run( form );
    }
```

I want to call RunForm() multiple times from the STAThread entry point:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        RunForm(); // Run form once
        RunForm(); // Run form twice
        RunForm(); // Run form etc.
    }
```

At some point, the form calls "Close()" on itself and unfortunately the application's thread exits and any subsequent call to RunForm() exits immediately...

But if I close the modal dialog manually by clicking the top-right red cross button, the subsequent calls to RunForm() work correctly (i.e. the application's thread is still running somehow).

How can I automatically run multiple modal dialogs in a sequence?
(and what is the difference between a manual close and a programmatic call to Close()?)

Answer (score 1):

[`Application.Run(ApplicationContext)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) is more likely a better fit for your usage of multiple forms by running just once this method and by handling the multiple open/closing forms from your application context implementation (as it is described in the link)

Comment: Alex's more detailed answer exactly is: don't run multiple contexts, use a single context and handle Open/Close form events